# Как установить Tkinter на мак

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, macos

> Вам не нужно устанавливать его через pip, его можно импортировать как import Tkinter на вашу оболочку или скрипт. @Не знаю как его зовут

Python 3.7.3, OS X Yosemite (10.9.5)

Я попробовал сделать выше написанное и у меня естесно ниче не получилось   (Шкальник + Код = Несовместимость)
[Вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827943/how-to-install-tkinter-on-mac/45828090#45828090)

```py
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import Tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

Буду благодарен если напишете последнюю версию VSC доступную на моем маке

Comment: В Python3 модуль tkinter пишется с маленькой буквы.

Comment: По поводу последней версии VSC - скорее всего для вас доступна самая новая существующая версия VSC. Но это не относится к основному вопросу. Не стоит задавать несколько вопросов в одном.